# Image bleeding over view Container in React Native

Tags: react-native

Having a slight issue with rendering an image within a view. The image renders fine, however, the container has a border radius which its not accommodating for. I have tried adding z-index in, but have had no luck. Any Ideas?

Code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

const Header = () => <Text style={styles.headerText}>What Is Asthma?</Text>;
const Body = () => (
    <Text style={styles.text}>
        The main symptoms of asthma include wheezing and shortness of main tre...
    </Text>
);

const ContentsCard = () => (
    <View style={{
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderRadius: 16,
        width: 350,
        height: 250,
    }}
    >
        <ImageBackground
            resizeMode="cover"
            style={{
                flex: 0.65,
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
            }}
            source={require('./ContentsExample/ExampleImage.jpg')}
        ><Text>wee</Text>
        </ImageBackground>
        <View style={{
            flex: 0.35,
            paddingLeft: 16,
            paddingRight: 16,
            paddingTop: 12,
        }}
        >
            {Header()}
            {Body()}
        </View>
    </View>
);

export default ContentsCard;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `overflow: hidden` to hide the image flowing over your view container

```
const ContentsCard = () => (
    <View style={{
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderRadius: 16,
        width: 350,
        height: 250,
        overflow: 'hidden',
    }}
    >
        <ImageBackground
            resizeMode="cover"
            style={{
                flex: 0.65,
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
            }}
            source={require('./ContentsExample/ExampleImage.jpg')}
        ><Text>wee</Text>
        </ImageBackground>
        <View style={{
            flex: 0.35,
            paddingLeft: 16,
            paddingRight: 16,
            paddingTop: 12,
        }}
        >
            {Header()}
            {Body()}
        </View>
    </View>
);

export default ContentsCard;
```